# Execute javascript in URL

Tags: javascript, browser

I know there is possibility to execute javascript code right in browser URL bar, for e.g. entering just `javascript:alert(1)`. Unfortunately I can't get it working on my mobile chrome or firefox even if the javascript execution is enable.